# Orient js list databases in orientdb

Tags: orientdb, orientjs

I have several databases in an orientdb server and am using Orient js and node js. I am trying to get the names of all the databases by using the server.list() method but can only get the length of the list which just tells me the number of total databases in my server.

How can I get the names of the databases using Orient js?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the RESTful HTTP protocol to get what you need:

Syntax: `http://<server>:<port>/listDatabases`

Source: [OrientDB REST > listDatabases](https://orientdb.com/docs/last/OrientDB-REST.html#list-databases)